# How to clean up third-party beans properly when Application shutdowns?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

what is the best way to `dispose` `DocumentNodeStore` in a Spring boot application when the server shutdowns?

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class MongoRepositoryInitializer {

.
.
.

    @Bean
    public DocumentNodeStore documentNodeStore(MongoClient mongoClient, MongoBlobStore mongoBlobStore) {
        return MongoDocumentNodeStoreBuilder
                .newMongoDocumentNodeStoreBuilder().setMongoDB(mongoClient, mongoDbName, 16)
                .setBlobStore(mongoBlobStore)
                .build();
    }
}
```

where should I call `documentNodeStore.dispose()` ? is this enough to clean up all mongo related staffs ?

Comment: can I define I `finalizer` bean and inject `documentNodeStore` into it, and call `dispose` method in a method of `finalizer` annotated with @destroy related annotation?

Comment: of course I can! (and I did, and I am not getting errors in the next start-up anymore ), I mean what is the best practice

Comment: Don't... The `finalize` method is a bad place to do that. Instead specify the `destroyMethod` on the `@Bean` annotation. Which will be called when the bean is destroyed.